# Do integer divisions to integers need a cast to float or double to be more precise?

Tags: c++, c, int, precision

If I wanted to divide 2 integers `a` and `b` to produce a third integer `c`, do I need to cast the division to float or double first before dividing to ensure maximum precision?

```
int a,b;
int c1 = a/b;        // without cast
int c2 = (float)a/b; // with cast
```

Thus is `c1` more, less or as precise as `c2`?

Comment: They're both "precise", it's simply a matter of what type of math you need, integer or floating point.  If you need a fractional result then use floating point types.  Note that you're assigning the result to an int here, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: Your code seems to remind one of: `Measure it with a micrometer, mark it with a chalk, cut it with an axe.`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you must restrict yourself from casting.

With large enough values, e.g. 1000000000L / 1000000001L is clearly 0, but when cast to float, it gives 1.0, since (float)a == (float)a+1.

```
main() {
    int a = 1000000000;
    printf("%d\n%d", a/(a+1), (int)((float)a/(a+1)));
}
```

Output:

```
0
1
```

Comment: To match what the OP was doing, wouldn't it be more like this: `main(){ int a=1000000000; printf("%d %d\n", a/(a+1), (int)((float)a/(a+1))); }`?

Comment: Thanks, this was what I wanted to know.

Comment: I just knew when I wrote my answer that there was some corner case I was forgetting.

Answer (score 1):

The precision you gain by using floating point division doesn't matter, as you're immediately throwing it away by the conversion to `int`. The result will be the same in either case.

Comment: The result won't *necessarily* be the same because converting from integer to floating point can incur a rounding error.

Comment: @Radiodef, I think (but can't prove off the top of my head) that any floating point result that is close to an integer will round to that integer.

Comment: @MarkRansom See the other answer for a counterexample to your claim.

Comment: Since `float` typically has 24-bit significands, any `int` that requires more than 24 significant bits will change when rounded to a `float`. Further, even if both operands are representable in `float`, there is a rounding error in the division. For example, `83886072 / 16777215` is 4, but `(float) 83886072 / 16777215` is 5.